# Block in a block not call in ad hoc archive ,but runs normal with xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, block

I got a very strange problem , my code runs as I think if I click the "Run" button in xcode

But after I archive it , and install it on the same iphone (4s , 6.1.3)

The block is not run as I think.

I was using the old ASIHttpRequest API.

Here is the code in my project

1.A singleton class handle the api call

```
    APICall.h

    typedef void (^CompleteHandler)(NSMutableArray *);

    - (void)listAllHistoryData:(CompleteHandler)theBlock;

    APICall.m

    - (void)listAllHistoryData:(CompleteHandler)theBlock{
    __weak ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:eWhereListAllDataURL];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSString *response = [request responseString];
        NSData *data = [response dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        _sessionList = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil] objectForKey:@"all_sessions"];
            theBlock(_sessionList);
    }];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

2.View controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [[APICall shareInstance] listAllHistoryData:^ (NSMutableArray *list) {
            dataList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:list];
            }
                [theTableView reloadData];
        }];
```

Just like I post these code ...

I can't see what's different after I archive my project .

Anyway thanks for any answer or comment

Webber

Comment: Have you tried debugging/running the code in Xcode, but on your device, instead of the simulator?

Comment: on instead , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local variable is __weak

ARC is allowed to nuke this reference the minute requestWithURL: ... returns (the return decrements the retain count, __weak doesn't increment it).  Your request variable is therefore going to be released and set to nil before you can call startAsynchronous on it.

Why did you make that local variable __weak?  There is no unbreakable retain cycle involved in your code when you remove it.  I believe that the completion block is nil'ed out (and released / destroyed) after it is invoked.

If this isn't the case, and you have a true leak here then you'll have to create another, non-weak reference to the ASIFormDataRequest so that it doesn't get blown away during your method.

The reason the AdHoc version doesn't work is because AdHoc is built with the Release target, which turns optimization on (and I believe causes LLVM to kill your objects via ARC in a more strict way).

Answer (score 0):

__weak Request got released in Xcode's Released Mode.
You can find these differences in Target - Build Settings - Optimization Level in Debug & Release.

Setting below classes appending "-O0" in Build Phases - Compile Sources 
ASIFormDataRequest.m
ASIHTTPRequest.m
works for me.

Hope it can help